# how to assign many points to labelled voronoi cell

Tags: image, mesh

I have [image: an image] and use it to generate a Voronoi lattice with following code:
    
    `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
    img = Import["1.JPG"];
    img = Binarize[ImageResize[img, {1000, 1500}]];
    imgt = ImageTrim[img, {{.0, .0}, {1.0, 0.8}},  DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];
(*distance transform create cell points*)
    k = DistanceTransform[ColorNegate[imgt]] // ImageAdjust;`

```
ReliefPlot[Reverse@ImageData[k]]; (*To illustrate*)
l = ColorNegate[ Binarize[ColorNegate[LaplacianGaussianFilter[k, 4] //ImageAdjust]]];(*generate voronoi lattice*)
meanValues = ComponentMeasurements[l, {"Centroid"}];
listData = meanValues /. Rule -> List;
listData = Partition[Flatten[listData[[All, 2]]], 2];(*seed center*)
imgBounds = Transpose[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[imgt]}];

vm = VoronoiMesh[listData, imgBounds, MeshCellLabel -> {2 -> "Index"}](*mesh region with boundary effects*)
```

After I got the mesh region and labelled each cell, I want to overlay this mesh lattice to every other images like this[image: images.]

```
smallSize = 190;
img1 = Import["2.JPG"];
img1 = Binarize[ImageResize[img1, {1000, 1500}]];
img1 = ImageTrim[img1, {{.0, .0}, {1.0, 0.8}}, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];(*imagetrim and import*)
k = DistanceTransform[ColorNegate[img1]] // ImageAdjust;ReliefPlot[Reverse@ImageData[k]]; (*To illustrate*)
l = ColorNegate[Binarize[ColorNegate[LaplacianGaussianFilter[k, 5] // ImageAdjust]]];
img1 = DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[img1], smallSize];
img1 = DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate[img1], smallSize];
img1 = ColorNegate[Binarize[img1]];
img1 = Closing[img1, DiskMatrix[4]];
```

So img1 is a binary image,which has black and white only. And vm is the mesh region i generate from frist image. I want to overlay the mesh region (vm) to binary image(img1), which can divided img1 into many labelled polygons.The next step I want to count how many  black and white pixels in each polygon as a list:

Ploygon  ;  black pixel number  ;  white pixel number

Comment: Have you tried anything so far in order to achieve your final goal?

Comment: yes, i tried overlay two images but since after overlaying images, the voronoi lattice data is missing, I cannot assign pixel positions to voronoi cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a starting point that might help you develop your own method. First, I select a sample image and binarize it; then generate some random points to construct a Voronoi mesh:

```
img = Binarize[ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Apples"}], 600]];

SeedRandom[123]
With[{bounds = {1, #} & /@ ImageDimensions[img]},
  pts = Floor@RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[bounds], 10];
  polys = MeshPrimitives[VoronoiMesh[pts, bounds], 2];
]

Show[
 img,
 Graphics[{
   Red, PointSize[0.015], Point@pts,
   EdgeForm[{Thick, Green}], FaceForm[], polys
 }]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Above the points are in red, and the resulting mesh is overlaid to the binarized picture.

We then extract the polygons composing the mesh, and generate a series of masks, each one containing a single polygon from the mesh in white. Each mask has the same size as the binarized image.

```
Graphics[
   {EdgeForm[Thick], polys, White, #},
   ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@img, PlotRangePadding -> None
] & /@ polys
```

Here is a sample mask:

[image: mask]

We now multiply the original image by each one of these masks to isolate the pixels in each polygon; all other pixels are thereby set to black.

```
ImageMultiply[
   img,
   Graphics[
     {EdgeForm[Thick], polys, White, #},
     ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@img, PlotRangePadding -> None
   ]
] & /@ polys
```

This would be the result obtained from the sample mask above:

[image: masked image]

To count the white pixels, we `Binarize` the resulting masked pictures, then extract the `ImageData` array representation, and sum across the array, knowing that white pixels contribute 1; black pixels 0. The total is thus the count of white pixels.

Putting it all together:

```
Total[
   ImageData@
    Binarize[
     ImageMultiply[
      img,
      Graphics[
        {EdgeForm[Thick], polys, White, #},
        ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@img, PlotRangePadding -> None
     ]
    ], 0], 2] & /@ polys

(* Out: {6523, 5791, 4290, 12279, 14486, 3196, 19214, 12937, 19640, 12483} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Marco, it works! yeah~~cheers

Comment: @ShuoqiLi I'm glad it helped!